# Kubernetes Heapster not working correctly

Tags: kubernetes, heapster

I set up kubernetes-dashboard and heapster according to the docs in the github. My kubernetes client and server version are both 1.5.4 and the whole cluster is deployed on 10 physical servers with ubuntu 14.04 OS. I used heapster 1.3.

I can access the dashboard and see some figures about cpu and memory usage, but I do not know why some pods do not have such figures, i.e., the cpu and memory usage of some pods are not displayed in figure format. The two pictures below are  examples.

[dashboard display 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQ45a.png)
[dashboard display 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmmsp.png)

Also, I find that sometimes for a pod, it only displays memory, without cpu usage.

I checked cAdvisor on each node by accessing its web ui, and it works quite well on each node. This problem troubles me several days. Can someone help me figure out this issue or give some hints? I'd be very grateful to you.

Comment: have you tried looking at heapster and cAdvisor pods logs?

Comment: Yes. I did not find any errors. Also, I check the url http://master:port/api/v1/proxy/nodes/node_ip/stats/ for each node, and it returns the statistics correctly

Comment: Finally I have figured it out. The bug is solved after time synchronization across servers.